# transform a byte array to a readablestream

Tags: javascript, stream, protocol-buffers

Hi I am stuck on this issue,

I reconstructed a few protobuf object in order to seed data to my miragejs instance,

```
  const unknownObject = new core.UnknownObject()
  const unknownEntity = new message.UnknownObjectEntity()
  const unknownEntityRepo = new message.UnknownObjectEntityRepository()
  const unknownObjectNotification = new message.UnknownObjectNotification()

  const date = new google_protobuf_timestamp_pb.Timestamp()

  unknownObject.setImage(Base64())
  unknownObject.setTimestamp(date)
  unknownObject.setWaypoint(new core.Waypoint())

  console.log('unknownObject:', unknownObject.getTimestamp())

  unknownEntity.setId('1')
  unknownEntity.setUnknownobject(unknownObject)

  console.log('unknownEntity:', unknownEntity)

  const endBuffer = unknownEntityRepo.addEntity(unknownEntity).serializeBinary()
```

the end result (endBuffer) is a byte array. I want to reconstruct this byte array into a readablestream in order to seed the data. This is the final result needed.

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
```

I can only fund resources made to be used to read the stream but never the transform a byte array into the ReadableStream.

Does anyone have experience with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement ReadableStream and add your content to the controller. [Mozilla's MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultController/enqueue) provide some guidance in their [simple random string example](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/streams/simple-random-stream/index.html).

Here is a simplified example:

```
function buildStream(data)
{
    //depending on what data is and how it will be used, you may need to convert it
    //data = Uint8Array.from(data);
    
    return new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
            // Add the data to the stream
            controller.enqueue(data);
        },
        pull(controller) {
            // nothing left to pull, so close
            controller.close();
        },
        cancel() {
            //nothing to do
        }
    });
}
```